# how to disable image

Tags: asp.net

I have one data grid,in each row of data grid,last column contain one image.
I want to hide that image which is in last column of each row.
Iam using asp.net1.1
So how to hide that image....
Or how to disable that image so that if user click on that image nothing sholid happened.

Answer (score 0):

just remove <a> anchor tag in which img tag is placed in datagrid code in html view. that will disable it. to remove image from the column, remove the complete  tag from the last column in datagrid in html view.